# Dataweave code in mule custom policy configuration

Tags: mule, mule-studio, policy, anypoint-studio, policies

I am working on creating custom policy in mule.

In configuration XML of the policy I am seeing various mule: transformers, set variable, loggers etc. while adding in before tag (`<before/>`) but dataweave.

I want to include dataweave code snippet in the configuration file (custom_policy.xml).

Can I have a chance to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the example here you can use dataweave transform message component in your custom policy:
refer: https://github.com/JeyaramD/mule-custom-jwt-policy/blob/master/jwt-validation-policy/jwt-validation-policy.xml

```
    <before>  

    .......
    .......
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" metadata:id="82cc8c48-d8bd-48aa-bf1d-ac1e7bc74f59">
        <dw:input-payload doc:sample="sample_data/json.json"/>
        <dw:input-variable variableName="jwtHeader"/>
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
    %output application/java
    ---
    "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" ++ payload.keys[?($.kid == flowVars.jwtHeader.x5t)].x5c[0][0] ++ "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
...............    
...............
```